# What units does iOS GPS return speeds in?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4, gps

I'm using the iPhone 4's built in GPS to return the date pos alt and speed.

However after looking for a long time I cant seem find what the speed is returned as, I know it's a double, but is this in meters per hour, feet, miles or what?

can anyone out there shed a clue???
thanks in advance.

Spriggsy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meters / second are the units of the speed

Answer (score 3):

If you read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/speed), you'll find that the very first thing it tells you is what units it's in (metres per second).

Answer (score 0):

If you read the EXIF tags standards doc, the allowable choices are K, M, or N for KpH, MpH, or Knots.  The value Apple sticks in the GPSSpeed Field is however m/s while using K for the GPSSpeedRef (which violates the EXIF Standards)